# How to use 'cbc' in pyomo's SolverFactory in Windows 10

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, solver, pyomo

I have been trying to use 'cbc' solver in pyomo as following:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

solver = pe.SolverFactory('cbc')

result = solver.solve(m)
```

Currently, I have been relying on the embedded solver with pyomo installation, which is 'glpk', and I have found that 'cbc' can do better job in many circumstances.

I am using:
python 3.XX

Anaconda environment

Windows 10

Pyomo (installed via Conda)

It would be great to upgrade the ability of pyomo by using advanced solver!

Comment: if [cplex solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437055/no-matching-distribution-found-for-cplex) can suit your task ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install `cbc` separately so that it can be used as a callable library.  I think the best place to start to look is here:

https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc/blob/master/README.md

That readme file talks about windows installation.  (I use mac...either path is a bit bumpy, but doable)

you may still need to build it from binaries...not too sure...  I'm not too experienced here, maybe others can pile on.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate the comment. I have followed the instructions on the github and I think either I missed something major or the instructions are not mentioning the details for my case.