# Jetson TX1: No matching distribution found for cplex

Tags: python, installation, cplex

I saw a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437055/no-matching-distribution-found-for-cplex) before, but I couldn't make it run.
I am trying to install cplex on a Jetson TX1 that runs Ubuntu 18.

When I run

```
$ pip install cplex

Collecting cplex
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cplex (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cplex
```

Here is what I get when I run the python commands:

```
$ which python 

/home/ubuntu/c4aarch64_installer/bin/python

$ python3 --version (same for python --version)

Python 3.7.2

$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

['', '/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/ubuntu/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python37.zip', '/home/ubuntu/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7', '/home/ubuntu/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/ubuntu/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7/site-packages']


$ echo $PYTHONPATH

/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I downloaded the cplex-22.1.1.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux1_x86_64.whl, unpacked it, and then moved cplex folder from cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib over to the Jetson TX1 $PYTHONPATH location.

Then I ran:

```
$ python3 

$ >>> import cplex
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib/cplex/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .aborter import Aborter
  File "/home/ubuntu/cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib/cplex/aborter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._internal import _procedural as _proc
  File "/home/ubuntu/cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib/cplex/_internal/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import _list_array_utils
  File "/home/ubuntu/cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib/cplex/_internal/_list_array_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex as CPX
  File "/home/ubuntu/cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib/cplex/_internal/_pycplex.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _pycplex_platform
  File "/home/ubuntu/cplex-22.1.1.1/cplex-22.1.1.1.data/purelib/cplex/_internal/_pycplex_platform.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cplex._internal.py37_cplex2211 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cplex._internal.py37_cplex2211'
```

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT**: I uninstalled ROS and set the python path to /home/ubuntu/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7/site-packages . Not sure if this was a correct move.

Comment: `manylinux1_x86_64` is targeting `x86_64` instruction-sets. Your board is ARM-based. Checking out [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-use-cplex-optimization-studio-2210-macosarm-machine) and [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-use-cplex-optimization-studio-2210-macosarm-machine), i wouldn't bother. Especially the first link does not make much sense and imho cplex is currently the worst-maintained commercial solver out there and whatever works towards ARM, it's probably only tested for Apple silicon and your hardware is somewhat less popular. Don't waste your time.

Comment: If i would have a need to do integer-programming on non apple-silicon ARM, i would go for [SCIP](https://www.pokutta.com/blog/random/2019/09/29/scipberry.html) and only SCIP. *CoinOR Cbc* build-tooling isn't much fun. *Highs* might work too. There are no big hurdles on a C/C++-based workflow. Targeting python, i guess things won't go as smooth howewer as [probably nobody prebuilts](https://pypi.org/project/PySCIPOpt/#files) ARM-based wheels

Comment: I tried installing pulp, but I kept getting many errors regarding cbc. I will checkout SCIP. Thanks!